# Does Pycharm debug work with python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, python-3.2

I'm on Mac OS X 10.8 and I've installed latest stable Python 3 (3.2.3) using Homebrew. Then I created a virtual environment using virtualenvwrapper - `mkvirtualenv --no-site-packages --python=/usr/local/bin/python3 py3` I've configured Pycharm to use this virtualenv and I can run scripts, but I can't debug them, when I press debug  Pycharm's debugger just quits:

```
/Users/qweqwe/.virtualenvs/py3/bin/python /Applications/PyCharm.app/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --client 127.0.0.1 --port 61596 --file /Users/qweqwe/Dropbox/Works/test/python/asyncore_test.py
pydev debugger: process 84441 is connecting
Connected to pydev debugger (build 117.663)

Process finished with exit code 132
```

Am I missing something or Pycharm just can't debug python3?

Update:
It doesn't work at all, no matter what the script is. Even when debugging single line hello world debugger exits with error

Comment: It doesn't work even with simple hello world scripts with single line like `print("Hello, I'm python 3!")`

Comment: This seems like a question of how to use an IDE, or possibly a bug report, and not actually a programming question per se.

Comment: @LennartRegebro, such questions are OK per this site FAQ: `software tools commonly used by programmers`.

Comment: I've create an issue http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-7171

Comment: Could you please set environment variable PYCHARM_DEBUG=True in you run configuration, debug your script and attach output to provided issue.

Comment: I know it's not the exact same, but I can verify that PyCharm 2.7.2 can debug python 3.3.1 on windows.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. enter this in pycharm settings/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/bin/python3(copied from [Python3/MacOSX integration into pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10078914/python3-macosx-integration-into-pycharm))

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem yesterday,and you can try in this way:
add

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

in your code ,
then set breakpoints and run Debugger.